# Move file or folder to a different folder in google document using api problem

Tags: c#, .net, google-code, google-docs-api, google-docs

In Google Document i have a struct:

```
Folder1
+------Folder1-1
+------+------File1-1-1
+------Folder1-2
+------File1-1
Folder2
```

I want to move "File1-1" to "Folder2" using .Net google api library([Google Data API SDK](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google%20Data%20API%20Setup%20%281.7.0.1%29.msi&can=2&q=))

```
public static void moveFolder(string szUserName, string szPassword, string szResouceID, string szToFolderResourceID)
    {
        string szSouceUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full"
            + "/" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(szResouceID);
        Uri sourceUri = new Uri(szSouceUrl);
        //create a atom entry
        AtomEntry atom = new AtomEntry();
        atom.Id = new AtomId(szSouceUrl);


        string szTargetUrl = "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3Aroot/contents/";
        if (szToFolderResourceID != "")
        {
            szTargetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full"
            + "/" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(szToFolderResourceID)
            + "/contents"
            ;
        }
        Uri targetUri = new Uri(szTargetUrl);


        DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService(SERVICENAME);
        ((GDataRequestFactory)service.RequestFactory).KeepAlive = false;
        service.setUserCredentials(szUserName, szPassword);

        service.EntrySend(targetUri, atom, GDataRequestType.Insert);


    }
```

After run this function i have:

```
Folder1
+------Folder1-1
+------+------File1-1-1
+------Folder1-2
+------File1-1
Folder2
+------File1-1
```

"File1-1" display in both "Folder1" and "Folder2", and when i delete it from a folder it will be deleted in another folder. (expect: "File1-1" display only in "Folder2")

What happen? How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [protocol docs](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#MovingIntoFolders) it seems to be a two step process.  Put File1-1 into Folder2, then delete file File1-1 from Folder1.  Is this not working?

Interestingly the [3.0 Python API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#FoldersMovingInAndOutOfFolder) makes it one step process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've solved my problem. I was move File1-1 to Folder2 and move File1-1 out of folder Folder1